# pop up info action point moves with opening a read more... div

Tags: css, wordpress, loops, html, popup

okay i got a jquery code with a read more... div working with in a loop (wordpress taxonomy). The only problem is that anytime i press read more... a toggle for a pop up moves down as well.

example: http://cloud0815.joloshop.com/shops/karstadt

if you open the hidden div (just press: "mehr Infos zum Gutschein..") and you mouseover the coupon code below a popup info is not opening (like on the first blue code box) Instead the toggle moves down about 40px.....

Im stuck again, sorry about my english, i am not native speaker, hence the german website...

THANKS

Comment: It would be more helpful for you and others if you could narrow down your problem by posting your javascript, html, and css in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: well its embedded in a big site and therefore almost impossible to do this with jsfiddle, i think i just missing a css code, just need a clue. The code is working perfect, its just somehow messing with other div on the side. Problem other div are moving and they are than not working properly anymore. :-(. I tried severall codes and having always the same problem. So there must be a simple css solution for this....

Comment: There are a few problems linking to a site that is not related to fiddle is that we don't know if it is a phishing site or any other malicious site. And more importantly, it is a pain to dive into a site that links to multiple css and js files. As I said, if you can give us an example with the bare minimum amount of code, it will help you and others to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can see why the issue would be a bit difficult to pinpoint, though in the future please try to provide some code, or at least screenshots detailing the problem to help others better understand what you're facing.

I believe the issue lies in the structure of your document. The `<div>` which triggers the tooltip to appear is not actually in the flow of the document - it is absolutely positioned. This means that when you expand the additional information, the rest of the document is moved, but the absolute-positioned trigger `<div>` stays where it originally was at the start. So the tooltip no longer appears when you hover over the coupon code, but instead where it used to be - because that's where the trigger `<div>` still is.

How to fix this? Well, you can just put the trigger `<div>` where it logically should exist in the structure. I'm not sure if the trigger elements are generated dynamically or not so I can't give exact implementation instructions. However, here's how a working structure could look:

```
<div class="couponAndTip">
    <div class="link-holder">
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; width: 93px; height: 100%; z-index: 99;">
            <embed id="ZeroClipboardMovie_2" src="http://cloud0815.joloshop.com/wp-content/themes/gutscheincloud/includes/js/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="93" height="24" name="ZeroClipboardMovie_2" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=2&amp;width=93&amp;height=24" wmode="transparent">
        </div>
        <a href="http://cloud0815.joloshop.com/go/karstadt-20prozent-rabatt-3/15381" id="coupon-link-15381" class="coupon-code-link" title="Code kopieren &amp; Shop öffnen " target="_blank">
            <span class="">bad20</span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- #link-holder -->
    <p class="link-popup" style="display: none;">
        <span>Code kopieren &amp; Shop öffnen </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

(This code was copied from one of the coupon code elements, and modified to include the trigger `<div>`). That `<div>` with the absolute positioning (and its contents) is the trigger for the tooltip, which I added to the HTML that I copied. You'll also need this CSS style to make it work properly:

```
.link-holder{
    position:relative;
}
```

And that's it. A bit of CSS, and some rearranging of the structure. However, I did notice that for each of the triggers, the width attribute varied and was set through inline CSS styling. This suggests dynamic generation, which means there might be some JavaScript to change. (On the other hand, if they're all just hard-coded, the task of rearranging them is a lot simpler.)

I hope this is what you're looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot, one step closer, its now working for the second code, the 3th, 4th etc.... is still messed up.......

Comment: just dont undertstand all this <embed id="ZeroClipboardMovie_2" src="http://cloud0815.joloshop.com/wp-content/themes/gutscheincloud/includes/js/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="93" height="24" name="ZeroClipboardMovie_2" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=2&amp;width=93&amp;height=24" wmode="transparent">

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know what it's there for either. It just behaved as the trigger, so I copied it without changing it.

Comment: @KaiNiermann If the structure of the document is hard-coded, you will have to similarly nest the tooltip triggers for every single coupon code element you have on the page.

Comment: hmm its in a loop and i had to ad the zeroclipboard stuff inside the theme-function.php.....

Comment: Unfortunately, further assistance will probably require diving into the generating PHP and possibly any relevant JS, which I don't believe is a feasible course of action here. The best I can offer is the above diagnosis of the problem. Hope you find a solution to it on your end!